# Variable doesn't exist error while assigning the id to field

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to update a particular field on account object on before insert or before update event in a method but it works for only one record when i assign 0 element to the field and if i remove the 0 reference then it throws me error 'variable doesn't exist:id'.

```
public static void accTerAssign(List<Account> accounts) {
        Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Account acc : accounts) {
            accIds.add(acc.OwnerId);
        }       
        Map<Id, List<Territory__c>> ownerTerMap = new Map<Id, List<Territory__c>>();
        if (!accIds.isEmpty()) {
            for(Territory__c t: [ SELECT Id, Name, Selling_Organization__c, OwnerId FROM Territory__c WHERE OwnerId IN :accIds]){
                if(!ownerTerMap.containsKey(t.OwnerId)) {
                    ownerTerMap.put(t.OwnerId, new List<Territory__c>());
                }
                ownerTerMap.get(t.OwnerId).add(t);
            }
        }
        for(Account acc : accounts) {
                        if(ownerTerMap.containsKey(acc.OwnerId) && ownerTerMap.get(acc.OwnerId).size() >= 1) {        
                acc.Territory__c = ownerTerMap.get(acc.OwnerId).Id;
            } else {
                system.debug('No territory exists'); 
            }           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ownerTerMap` contains lists, yet you have the following:

```
acc.Territory__c = ownerTerMap.get(acc.OwnerId).Id;
```

This won't work because a list doesn't have an ID. Basically `ownerTerMap.get(acc.OwnerId)` is returning a list of territories.

How you fix this depends on what your requirement is. One option would be to always use the first entry in the list:

```
acc.Territory__c = ownerTerMap.get(acc.OwnerId)[0].Id;
```

NB: Your code already checked before this that there is a list and it isn't empty so this will work.

PS: You can improve the performance, since you don't need to explicitly support a "null" entry in your map, by always using `Map.get` and never calling `Map.containsKey`.

Comment: Was literally writing the answer, but you were faster :)

Comment: @phil exactly when i give the 0th element reference it works, but if i have more than 1 element and i don't want to access the 0th element instead i want to access 3rd elment then how can i get that element..

Comment: @SFDCKASH use of `[0]` or any other index comes down to your specific requirements. I cannot comment.

Comment: @PhilW I do have such requirement where i have to get any element and that is where i am struggling with. It would be really great if you can just give any inputs on this.

Comment: Clearly in this object model you can only relate the account to a single territory. If you have multiple possible territories you need to have some way to choose just one of them, be that automatically or with user intervention. Alternatively, change the object model to allow an account to be related to multiple territories (probably via some junction object).